# Understanding plt.norm and plt.cbar using Practical example

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am learning to make color bars, and thus learning to make good use of plt.Normalize , I succeeded to make it work with scipy.stats.norm, but when tryin to use plt.norm, I found out that I have to do two things to make it work well :

- defining vmin and vmax to -1.96 and 1.96 respectively,I guess that it's because they are the z value for 95% confidence interval, but I still don't precisely know why they have we have to set vmin and vmax to those values
- dividing the standard deviation by sqrt( number of elements )

I don't understand why are those two points important for using the Norm. Any help is welcome ! thank you in advance

```
# Use the following data for this assignment:
%matplotlib notebook
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as st

df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.normal(33500,150000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(41000,90000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(41000,120000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(48000,55000,3650)], 
                  index=[1992,1993,1994,1995])

new_df = pd.DataFrame()
new_df['mean'] = df.mean(axis =1)
new_df['std'] = df.std(axis =1)
new_df['se'] = df.sem(axis= 1)
new_df['C_low'] = new_df['mean'] - 1.96 * new_df['se']
new_df['C_high'] = new_df['mean'] + 1.96 * new_df['se']

from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np
# First, Define a figure
fig = plt.figure()
# next define its the axis and create a plot 
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
# change the ticks
xticks = np.array(new_df.index,dtype= 'str')
# remove the top and right borders
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
# draw the bars in the axis
bars = ax.bar(xticks,new_df['mean'].values,
             yerr = (1.96*new_df['se'],1.96*new_df['se']),
             capsize= 10)
# define labels
plt.xlabel('YEARS',size = 14)
plt.ylabel('FREQUENCY',size = 14)
# Define color map
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('coolwarm')
# define scalar mappable 
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap = cmap)
# draw the color bar
cbar = plt.colorbar(cmap = cmap, mappable =sm)
# define norm (will be used later to turn y to a value from 0 to 1 )

# define the events
class Cursor(object):
    def __init__(self,ax):
        self.ax = ax
        self.lx = ax.axhline(color = 'c')
        self.txt = ax.text(1,50000,'')
    def mouse_movemnt(self,event):
        #behaviour outside of the plot
        if not event.inaxes:
            return
        #behavior inside the plot
        y = event.ydata
        self.lx.set_ydata(y)

        for idx,bar in zip(new_df.index, bars):
            norm = plt.Normalize(vmin =-1.96,vmax = 1.96)
            mean = new_df.loc[idx,'mean']
            err = new_df.loc[idx, 'se']
            std = new_df.loc[idx,'std']/ np.sqrt(df.shape[1]) # not sure why we re dividing by np.sqrt(df.shape[1])
            self.txt.set_text(f'Y = {round(y,2)} \n')
            color_prob = norm( (mean - y)/std)
            #color_prob = norm.cdf(y,loc = mean, scale = err) # you can also use this 
            bar.set_color(  cmap(color_prob))



# connect the events to the plot
cursor = Cursor(ax)
plt.connect('motion_notify_event', cursor.mouse_movemnt)
None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few hours of thinking, an explanation barged into my head and I was able to answer all of my inquiries,

first before answering the first point, I will answer the second one, the standard deviation was divided by the sqrt(nbr of element) because the resulting value is the standard error.

I will now move on to answering the first part:
(I can't embed images for now and I can't use latex either so I have to put links of the image instead). But here is the conclusion in advance, for all values within that confidence interval, the function (y-mean)/se will spit out a value within the range [−1.96,1.96]

[answer of first part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EW0bm.png)

Please, if I left something out or you have a better answer, share it with me.